# Trying to get header over the first element with the value of specific date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a time tracking app. My problem is that i am trying to render a "date header" over the first element that includes a specific date value. I am using cloud firestore.

I was thinking of solution where I would be able to split the retrieved array in chunks based on the date — meaning e.g. 25/07/2020 = Would group all the times from that day an then render a header over the first element of that chunk. But I have no idea how to execute that.

I will explain with screenshots.

Where I am now:

[image]

Where I am trying to get:

[image]

This is my code in the component that handles most of the firestore events:

```
// Main Render
const Times = props => {
  // Handling the state
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(''); // Hours
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(''); // Minutes
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(''); // Description
  const [entry, setEntry] = useState([]);
  const [isStopped, setIsStopped] = useState(true); // Lottie animation state
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Loading state

  const time_entry = useEntries();

  // Update all inputs as you type
  const handleHoursChange = event => {
    setHours(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleMinutesChange = event => {
    setMinutes(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDescriptionChange = event => {
    setDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  // Lottie: initial settings
  const defaultOptions = {
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    animationData: animationData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice'
    }
  };

  // Get entries on app load
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
      });
  }, []);

  // Load all documents from firebase collection on initial app load
  function useEntries() {
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase.db
        .collection('time_entries')
        .orderBy('createdOn.timestamp', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const newEntry = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          }));

          setEntry(newEntry);
        });
    }, []);

    return entry;
  }

  // Date variable
  var date = new Date();

  // Send entry onSubmit
  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Perform lottie animation
    setIsStopped(false);
    setTimeout(() => setIsStopped(true), 400);

    firebase.db
      .collection('time_entries')
      .add({
        description,
        hours,
        minutes,
        createdOn: {
          date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
          time: date.toLocaleTimeString(),
          timestamp: date.toLocaleString()
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        setDescription('');
        setHours('');
        setMinutes('');
      });
  }

  return (
    <section className="Times">
      <div style={{ maxWidth: props.width, width: '100%' }}>
        <form className="Form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div className="TimeInput">
            <TimeSelect
              variant="dropdown"
              unit="hours"
              value={hours}
              onChange={handleHoursChange}
            />
            <span>:</span>
            <TimeSelect
              variant="dropdown"
              unit="minutes"
              value={minutes}
              onChange={handleMinutesChange}
            />
          </div>
          <input
            className="TextInput"
            value={description}
            placeholder="What have you done?"
            onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
          />
          <div className="SubmitAnimation">
            <Lottie
              options={defaultOptions}
              height={100}
              width={100}
              isStopped={isStopped}
              speed={1.5}
            />
          </div>

          <ButtonBase className="Button" type="submit" focusRipple>
            <Check color="white" size={24} strokeWidth={3} />
          </ButtonBase>
        </form>

        <span className="ItemsHeader">
          <p2>Time entries</p2>
          <div className="TimeTotal">
            <Clock className="Icon" size={16} strokeWidth="3" />
            <p2>
              Total: <span>15h 30min</span>
            </p2>
          </div>
        </span>

        {time_entry.map(time_entry => (
          <>
            {loading ? (
              <>
                <FadeIn>
                  <Placeholder />
                </FadeIn>
              </>
            ) : (
              <FadeIn>
                <TimeItem
                  hours={time_entry.hours}
                  minutes={time_entry.minutes}
                  description={time_entry.description}
                  date={time_entry.createdOn.timestamp}
                  doc_id={time_entry.id}
                />
              </FadeIn>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Times;
```

Screenshot from firebase (for better imagination of how I structured my data):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a collection object mapping the dates to a list of the entries on that date - you can do this with a simple `reduce`, which I have provided below.

```js
const testData = [
  { id: "1", time: '2020-07-24T02:00:00.000Z'},
  { id: "2", time: '2020-07-25T15:00:00.000Z'},
  { id: "3", time: '2020-05-24T12:00:00.000Z'},
  { id: "4", time: '2020-06-24T17:00:00.000Z'},
  { id: "5", time: '2020-07-25T04:00:00.000Z'},
  { id: "6", time: '2020-07-15T19:00:00.000Z'},
  { id: "7", time: '2020-07-15T23:00:00.000Z'},
];

const splitIntoDays = (entries) => entries.reduce((collection, entry) => {
  const date = new Date(entry.time).toDateString()
  collection[date] = [...(collection[date] || []), entry]
  return collection;
}, {})


console.log(splitIntoDays(testData));
```

Then you can use this method inside your `onSnapshot` to set the state to this reduced object.
Your `useEffect` needs to be on the root of the component, which will run it once on mount, getting and subscribing to Firestore. Don't return anything from that, just set the state.

```
setEntriesSplitByDate(splitIntoDays(newEntries));
```

Then later in your render method, extract the `keys` (which will be the date strings) from that object, display the date string in your header (`h2`), and have a second, nested map that maps through the entries in that chunk's list, rendering an `Entry` per item.

```
    <section>
      {Object.keys(entriesSplitByDate).map(dateKey => (
        <div key={dateKey}>
          <h2>{dateKey}</h2>
          {entriesSplitByDate[dateKey].map(entry => (
            <EntryItem entry={entry} />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
```

[Sandbox of working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-wu-xiyez?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yeees! Thank you. I have gotten to solve the first part where I needed to divide the data into chunks by date. Sadly I am still not understanding enough the mapping part right now.

Comment: So `map` basically goes through each of those chunks and does something for them, in this case returns a div

Comment: I understand the concept of mapping itself. I am just having a problem inmolementing your example into my use case. Specifically i dont know what i should put instead of dateToEntriesObject

Comment: That should be the object that is the result of the reduce. Depending on how you're storing state, you can probably calculate it just before the `return`, or I think you can di it inside the `useEntries` method, as soon as you grab them from Firestore, which would be the cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: yeah so how I approached the reduce on the app lod is like this now:

Comment: const splitIntoDays = entries =>
            entries.reduce((collection, entry) => {
              const date = new Date(entry.createdOn.timestamp).toDateString();
              collection[date] = [...(collection[date] || []), entry];
              return collection;
            }, {});

Comment: I put this function into my useEffect function to run on the app load, but now I do not know how to approach it with the TimeItem component inside of my render

Comment: delete `timeEntry`, get rid of the `useEntries` wrapper function and just put that `useEffect` on the root of the component. Maybe delete the other `useEffect` with `jsonplaceholder`, I've not sure what that does.

Comment: Rename `setEntry` to `setEntriesSplitByDate`.

Then instead of trying to `return entry;`, you can get the firestore to load on app init, then inside that `useEffect` you do   `setEntriesSplitByDate(splitIntoDays(newEntry))` which will set the state, which you can then map by later on

Comment: Okay that makes my code way clearer! But I am still struggling with the mapping part :( could you maybe showcase how would you structure the map in my case exactly?

Comment: Yeah I've written it all out here https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-wu-xiyez?file=/src/App.js:1163-1217